# OOB Webparts to find count of items in list

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-foundation

Is there any out of the box way of finding the count of items in a list?

Answer (score 0):

if you want to **show that in a view** then there is option to show the count of the list.
there would be a option called totals in the view where you can configure the column which count you want, to get all item count you can use "Id" column as shown below

[image]

**but if you apply any filter to that then it would show  only the count of filtered items**

Comment: do u mean to have data view web part and have count has a column

Comment: In my case i want to have count based on the filter wat user apply

Comment: ya,you can create views and apply the above property,if you want it in a specific page then create the view include it as webpart to the page.

Answer (score 0):

Click on Site Contents link. Locate your list. Here you will find the number of items in the list and Last Modified Date.